# Accessing a value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access the country names from this json -

```
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all
```

This is my code for loading that json -

```
<script>
      (function() {
           var country = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all";
           $.getJSON( country)
           .done(function( data ) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#mySelect').empty();
                    $('#myselect').append('<option>' + data.name + '</option>');
                });
             });
         })();

  </script>
```

The problem may be in **data.name** statement. I couldn't find any solution on my own. Plus, i am new to JSON. Any help or at least any comment to point my faults will be appreciated.

Comment: what is inside `data`?

Comment: May be data from JSON ? I assumed/moved forward on the basis on that concept.

Comment: Post the JSON data returned by that URL, for example `console.log(data)`.

Comment: @Aaron Tried your suggestion and data is getting all the JSON data.

Comment: I'm asking you to post the actual JSON data in your question.

Comment: Also, you haven't actually asked a question. What is the problem? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: @Aaron It is my fault. I couldn't construct the question fruitfully. The data in JSON is huge. That's why, i didn't post it to my question. My query was to find out problems/faults in my code. I will try to be more precise next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `value.name`, `data` is the array you get from the api, `value` is each item in the array. also, remove `empty` as it's remove everything in each loop cyle...

see working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b8cxo01m/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have used empty because, data inside options need to cleared every time my page is load. I have heard that this is a good practice.

Comment: you can use it outside of `each` loop since it'd remove everything each time an item is added if you put in in the loop which leaves you with only the last option - zimbabwe :)